# How can I ensure I still get correct touch inputs when my scene is offset?

Tags: cocoa-touch, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How can I accept touch input beyond the scene's bounds, so that no matter what I set `self.position` to, touches can still be detected?

I'm creating a tile based game from Ray Winderlich on Cocos2d version 3.0. I am at the point of setting the view of the screen to a zoomed in state on my tile map. I have successfully been able to do that although now my touches are not responding since I'm out of the coordinate space the touches used to work on.

This method is called to set the zoomed view to the player's position:

```
-(void)setViewPointCenter:(CGPoint)position{
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSizeInPixels;
    int x = MAX(position.x, winSize.width/2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, winSize.height/2);
    x = MIN(x, (_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width) - winSize.width / 2);
    y = MIN(y, (_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - winSize.height / 2);
    CGPoint actualPosition = ccp(x, y);

    CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    NSLog(@"centerOfView%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(centerOfView));
    CGPoint viewPoint = ccpSub(centerOfView, actualPosition);
    NSLog(@"viewPoint%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(viewPoint));

    //This changes the position of the helloworld layer/scene so that
    //we can see the portion of the tilemap we're interested in.
    //That however makes my touchbegan method stop firing 
    self.position = viewPoint;
}
```

This is what the `NSLog` prints from the method:

```
2014-01-30 07:05:08.725 TestingTouch[593:60b] centerOfView{512, 384}
2014-01-30 07:05:08.727 TestingTouch[593:60b] viewPoint{0, -832}
```

As you can see the y coordinate is `-800`. If i comment out the line `self.position = viewPoint` then the `self.position` reads `{0, 0}` and touches are detectable again but then we don't have a zoomed view on the character. Instead it shows the view on the bottom left of the map.

Here's a [video demonstration](http://speedy.sh/mpBbN/TouchProblem.mov).

How can I fix this?

**Update 1**

Here is the [github page](http://github.com/pavankataria/TileBasedGame) to my repository.

**Update 2**
Mark has been able to come up with a temporary solution so far by setting the `hitAreaExpansion` to a large number like so:

```
self.hitAreaExpansion = 10000000.0f;
```

This will cause touches to respond again all over! However, if there is a solution that would not require me to set the property with an absolute number then that would be great!

Comment: Have the decency to explain why you downvoted! It frustrates me when I see people abusing the downvote button. If you read the question carefully, you can gather a few things: 1) I am new to cocos2d however I'm not being a noob by saying I don't know what to do, instead I have taken the initiative to try and isolate the problem to 1 specific line. 2) My question that's now isolated to a specific problem has been carefully written to make sure its right to the point, I ask for help for something specific, this question is NOT broad at all! So do me a favour and fix up mate, read the help page.

Comment: does the touchBegan method actually stop firing or it stops producing the expected result ? if it fires, you may be working in the wrong coordinate system unwittingly ie it works fine as long as the position is dead center on screen center. I would not know how to prevent a touch event to fire by changing the position of an object.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg It does not fire at all which is not what I want, atleast if it was still firing then I could do some other things, but its not firing at all, its as though settng the position property causes the screen to be outside the touch boundaries. Please have a look at the video demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-edit 3-(tldr version):**
setting the contentsize of the scene/layer to the size of the tilemap solves this issue:

`[self setContentSize: self.tileMap.contentSize];`

---

**original replies below:**

You would take the touch coordinate and subtract the layer position.

Generally something like:

```
touchLocation = ccpSub(touchLocation, self.position);
```

if you were to scale the layer, you would also need appropriate translation for that as well.

**-edit 1-**:

So, I had a chance to take another look, and it looks like my 'ridiculous' number was not ridiculous enough, or I had made another change. Anyway, if you simply add

```
self.hitAreaExpansion = 10000000.0f; // I'll let you find a more reasonable number
```

the touches will now get registered.

As for the underlying issue, I believe it to be one of content scale that is not set correctly, but again, I'll now leave that to you. I did however find out that when looking through some of the tilemap class, that tilesize is said to be in pixels, not points, which I guess is somehow related to this.

**-edit 2-:**

It bugged me with the sub-optimal answer, so I looked a little further. Forgive me, I hadn't looked at v3 until I saw this question. :p

after inspecting the base class and observing the scene/layer's value of:

```
- (BOOL)hitTestWithWorldPos:(CGPoint)pos;
```

it became obvious that the content size of the scene/layer was being set to the current view size, which in the case of an iPad is (1024, 768)

The position of the layer after the `setViewPointCenter` call is fully above the initial view's position, hence, the touch was being suppressed. by setting the layer/scene `contentSize` to the size of the tilemap, the touchable area is now expanded over the entire map, which allows the node to process the touch.

Comment: Hi mark, thank you for posting, please have a look at the video demonstration. I would take the touch coordinate if the touch event was even being fired at the first place, as I have shown in the video, its as though offsetting the position causes be to be outside of the touch boundaries where touch event would normally be registered with.

Comment: Hi mark, sorry, i've included the video demonstration now. Please do take a look and thank you for taking the time to write a response.

Comment: Oh, I must have missed the part earlier where you said the touch events were not fired after moving the layer. I have not had that happen to me, but I would guess something else is to blame outside of the code posted. Sorry. If this is just a test project for you, perhaps posting the whole thing up on [git host] would make things clearer?

Comment: Sure mark, I can do that. I will post the link soon

Comment: indeed, it doesn't seem to like the layer/scene being moved. if you move the tilemap(    self.tileMap.position = viewPoint;
), it works, sort of .. at least for the bottom left quadrant of the map. If I were you, I would perhaps explore hanging everything off of your own supernode that hangs off of the parent layer, i.e. self.interactionLayer, and do your positioning off of that node.. and then I'd ask the v3 developers if there is something to moving the base layer.

Comment: As an aside, this was my first look around v3, so thank you for the push. I see that there is a _hitAreaExpansion which allows for expanding the interaction area of a node. I tried bumping that up to a ridiculous number and it still didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for exploring the repository. I am a 3 day old `cocos2d` developer xD ! I have absolutely no clue what you're talking about! I was simply following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on `how to create an RPG tile based game`, but decided to use the updated `vocos2d-3.0` version instead of what Ray used - `2.0`. I managed to use the new methods instead of the depreciated methods, but couldn't succesfully get touch to work Yes, the left quadrant does work if you comment the `self.position` line out.

Comment: perhaps you could explore the first page of the tutorial? It's dead easy to follow, infact you can just pick up on my repository and go to this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x and skip to the paragraph heading: **Making the Ninja Move**. It's at this bit where things go funky since he wants us to use the `-(void)registerWithTouchDispatcher` method but I assumed thats not needed in `cocos2d-3.0` since touches are automatically registered? aha I could be wrong, but do check it out pls.

Comment: I've updated my answer with at least a temporary solution: set `self.hitAreaExpansion = <a big number>` to get touches working for the entire map

Comment: aha, thats awesome, my ninja is now travelling all over the map! thanks buddy! If you happen to find out how to get this working with content scale then that would be awesome and I would be happy for you to update me; for now though, your solution suffices. Cheers again!

Comment: so, just to come full circle on this and give a proper answer, it's basically that the size of the tilemap was bigger than the scene/layer. by setting the content size of the scene/layer to the content size of the tilemap, the touch was allowed to be processed.(i.e. `[self setContentSize: self.tileMap.contentSize];` ) I've updated the answer with this info.

Comment: Hey dude, thats exactly what I wanted to do, i wanted to set the size of the touch boundary based on the size of the map, but then I got stumped when I saw that the hitExpansion property would only accept a single digit. It had me scratching my head on where it was that I could update the touch boundary. But based on your answer it seems the touch boundary is associated with the scene's contentSize. So then its the scene you want to update so the touches automatically stretch to all corners of the map. Awesome mark! I appreciate your update.

Comment: I had also posted the question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69537/how-can-i-ensure-i-still-get-correct-touch-inputs-when-my-scene-is-offset should I leave that question be or should I just delete it?

Comment: Not exactly sure of the proper etiquette, but perhaps just cross link back to this question, especially since there were a couple of replies over there.?